# Count of country of other users

Tags: postgresql

I have three tables **trip_country_sets**, **users** and **trip**.

```
CREATE TABLE trip_country_sets (
tc_set_id varchar PRIMARY KEY,
trip_id varchar,
user_id varchar,
country varchar
);

CREATE TABLE users (
user_id varchar PRIMARY KEY,
name_t varchar
);

CREATE TABLE trip (
trip_id varchar PRIMARY KEY,
owner_id varchar,
title varchar
);insert into trip_country_sets values('tc1', 'trip1', 'usr1', 'counrty_test1');
insert into trip_country_sets values('tc2', 'trip2', 'usr2', 'counrty_test1');
insert into trip_country_sets values('tc3', 'trip3', 'usr3', 'counrty_test2');
insert into trip_country_sets values('tc4', 'trip4', 'usr1', 'counrty_test2');
insert into trip_country_sets values('tc5', 'trip5', 'usr2', 'counrty_test3');
insert into trip_country_sets values('tc6', 'trip6', 'usr3', 'counrty_test3');
insert into trip_country_sets values('tc7', 'trip3', 'usr1', 'counrty_test4');
insert into trip_country_sets values('tc8', 'trip4', 'usr2', 'counrty_test4');
insert into trip_country_sets values('tc9', 'trip1', 'usr3', 'counrty_test5');
insert into trip_country_sets values('tc10', 'trip2', 'usr1', 'counrty_test5');
insert into trip_country_sets values('tc11', 'trip1', 'usr2', 'counrty_test1');
insert into trip_country_sets values('tc12', 'trip1', 'usr3', 'counrty_test1');
insert into trip_country_sets values('tc13', 'trip4', 'usr2', 'counrty_test3');
insert into trip_country_sets values('tc14', 'trip5', 'usr1', 'counrty_test5');
insert into trip_country_sets values('tc15', 'trip6', 'usr2', 'counrty_test6');
insert into trip_country_sets values('tc16', 'trip2', 'usr3', 'counrty_test3');
insert into trip_country_sets values('tc17', 'trip1', 'usr2', 'counrty_test5');

insert into users values('usr1', 'name1');
insert into users values('usr2', 'name2');
insert into users values('usr3', 'name3');

insert into trip values('trip1', 'usr1', 'title1');
insert into trip values('trip2', 'usr2', 'title2');
insert into trip values('trip3', 'usr3', 'title3');
insert into trip values('trip4', 'usr1', 'title4');
insert into trip values('trip5', 'usr5', 'title5');
insert into trip values('trip6', 'usr1', 'title6');
insert into trip values('trip7', 'usr4', 'title4');
insert into trip values('trip8', 'usr1', 'title5');
insert into trip values('trip9', 'usr6', 'title6');
```

How to make a query that will find all the **countries** of the user, the **number of countries** that do not belong to the user.

```
select
    trip_country_sets.country,
    count(distinct trip_country_sets.tc_set_id) as country_count
from trip_country_sets
    LEFT OUTER join trip on trip_country_sets.trip_id = trip.trip_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN users on trip_country_sets.user_id = users.user_id
where
    trip.owner_id = 'usr1'
    and trip_country_sets.user_id <> 'usr1'
group by trip_country_sets.country, trip_country_sets.tc_set_id;
```

The result of my query affects only the **countries** and **counts** of country from the **trip_country_sets** table. The **WHERE** the values are involved in the definition of the query *trip.owner_id = 'usr1'* and *trip_country_sets.user_id <> 'usr1'*
I want the following result:

```
---------------------------------
|    country    | country_count |
---------------------------------
| counrty_test1 |       2       |
| counrty_test3 |       2       |
| counrty_test6 |       1       |
| counrty_test5 |       2       |
| counrty_test4 |       1       |
```

Work example:
https://rextester.com/live/GOKNM17080

Comment: Can you please explain your desired output a little better?  For example, what are the numbers in the first column, and what is country_test6 doing as an output row, when usr1 has not visited it (according to your test data)?

Comment: @JonathanWillcock I have fixed my desired result. I need to get two columns country country_count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Maybe I didn't explain the question exactly. Here is my search query, this is the correct answer:

```
select
    trip_country_sets.country,
    count(distinct trip_country_sets.tc_set_id) as country_count
from trip_country_sets
    LEFT OUTER join trip on trip_country_sets.trip_id = trip.trip_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN users on trip_country_sets.user_id = users.user_id
where
    trip.owner_id = 'usr1'
    and trip_country_sets.user_id <> 'usr1'
group by trip_country_sets.country;
```

This query returns my desired result:

```
---------------------------------
|    country    | country_count |
---------------------------------
| counrty_test1 |       2       |
| counrty_test3 |       2       |
| counrty_test6 |       1       |
| counrty_test5 |       2       |
| counrty_test4 |       1       |
```

Comment: Glad to hear! The sentence *the number of countries that do not belong to the user.* made it sound like your question was exactly the opposite of what you wanted. Keep that in mind in the future (:

Answer (score 1):

If you want, per user, a list of countries that do belong to the user, and the number of countries that the user is still missing, consider the following:

```sql
-- First, count the number of countries that a user can have
WITH total_countries AS (
  SELECT COUNT(distinct country) total
  FROM trip_country_sets
)
SELECT users.id, -- or name
       ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT country), -- DISTINCT if the user can have multiple trips
       (SELECT total FROM total_countries) - COUNT(DISTINCT country) as missing_countries
FROM users
LEFT OUTER JOIN trip_country_sets on trip_country_sets.user_id = users.user_id
GROUP BY users.id
```

Comment: I'm sorry . I need to get two columns country and country_count.