# SQL Query to find Customers who order exact same order list more than once in 2 months

Tags: sql, databricks, databricks-sql

I want to extract data to find Customers who have ordered exact same order list (Repeated exact order) more than once in span of latest 2 months. For both the orders the quantity purchased, and items should be same. Please let me know if any further explanation is needed. Thanks for your help!

Let's say I have the following data (Order Table and Order Items Table)-

Order Table contains data like Order_No, Customer ID, Order Status, Order Date

```
| Order no | Customer ID | Order Status | Order Date |
|:-------- |:-----------:| :-----------:| ----------:|
|   123    |      A      |   Complete   | 7/1/2022   |
|   321    |      A      |   Complete   | 10/23/2022 |
|   231    |      A      |   Complete   | 8/12/2022  |
|   1981   |      B      |   Complete   | 9/18/2022  |
```

Order Items Table contains data like Order_No, Order Items, Order Quantity

```
| Order no |             Order Items              | Order Quantity | 
|:-------- |:------------------------------------:| --------------:| 
|   123    |           Matrix Serum 250ml         |        1       | 
|   123    |         Sunsilk Shampoo 340ml        |        1       | 
|   123    |      Sunsilk conditioner 110 ml      |        2       |
|   321    |           Matrix Serum 250ml         |        1       |
|   321    |         Pantene Shampoo 340ml        |        1       |
|   231    |           Matrix Serum 250ml         |        1       | 
|   231    |         Sunsilk Shampoo 340ml        |        1       | 
|   231    |      Sunsilk conditioner 110 ml      |        2       |
|   1981   |           Matrix Serum 250ml         |        1       | 
|   1981   |         Sunsilk Shampoo 340ml        |        1       | 
|   1981   |      Sunsilk conditioner 110 ml      |        2       |
```

**For Example: ** Dataset (Merged table view called Orders)

```
Customer A, Order 123, (Order Date 7/1/2022), Order Items (1 Matrix Serum 250ml, 1 Sunsilk Shampoo 340ml, 2 Sunsilk conditioner 110 ml each)
Customer A, Order 321, (Order Date 10/23/2022), Order Items (1 Matrix Serum 250ml, 1 Pantene Shampoo 340ml)
Customer A, Order 231, (Order Date 8/12/2022), Order Items (1 Matrix Serum 250ml, 1 Sunsilk Shampoo 340ml, 2 Sunsilk conditioner 110 ml each)
Customer B, Order 1981, (Order Date 9/18/2022), Order Items (1 Matrix Serum 250ml, 1 Sunsilk Shampoo 340ml, 2 Sunsilk conditioner 110 ml each)
```

**Expected Result**: Query output should provide Customer A because **Customer A** has ordered exact same order twice on 7/1/2022 and 8/12/2022

```
| Order no |  Customer  | Order Date |             Order Items              | Order Quantity | 
|:-------- |:----------:|:----------:|:------------------------------------:| --------------:|
|   123    |      A     |  7/1/2022  |           Matrix Serum 250ml         |        1       |
|   123    |      A     |  7/1/2022  |         Sunsilk Shampoo 340ml        |        1       |
|   123    |      A     |  7/1/2022  |      Sunsilk conditioner 110 ml      |        2       |
|   231    |      A     |  8/12/2022 |           Matrix Serum 250ml         |        1       |
|   231    |      A     |  8/12/2022 |         Sunsilk Shampoo 340ml        |        1       |
|   231    |      A     |  8/12/2022 |      Sunsilk conditioner 110 ml      |        2       |
```

Query I tried -

```
Select * from orders
Where (customer id, order items) IN 
(Select customer id, order items
  From orders t
  Group by customer id, order items
Having count(1) > 1)
```

This query is not correctly filtering out the customers who purchased same products and quantity in latest 2 months. It is checking one line item across all orders and not all of the items in one order.

Actual result I am getting through this query:

```
| Order no |  Customer  | Order Date |             Order Items              | Order Quantity | 
|:-------- |:----------:|:----------:|:------------------------------------:| --------------:|
|   123    |      A     |  7/1/2022  |           Matrix Serum 250ml         |        1       |
|   123    |      A     |  7/1/2022  |         Sunsilk Shampoo 340ml        |        1       |
|   123    |      A     |  7/1/2022  |      Sunsilk conditioner 110 ml      |        2       |
|   321    |      A     | 10/23/2022 |           Matrix Serum 250ml         |        1       |
|   231    |      A     |  8/12/2022 |           Matrix Serum 250ml         |        1       |
|   231    |      A     |  8/12/2022 |         Sunsilk Shampoo 340ml        |        1       |
|   231    |      A     |  8/12/2022 |      Sunsilk conditioner 110 ml      |        2       |
|   1981   |      B     |  9/18/2022 |           Matrix Serum 250ml         |        1       |
|   1981   |      B     |  9/18/2022 |         Sunsilk Shampoo 340ml        |        1       |
```

Comment: Please show your order tables as columns for example.

Comment: Added Table format

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you provided, I can suggest the following query:

```
select *
  from orders
  left join order_items oi on orders.order_no = oi.order_no
where
  orders.customer = oi.customer 
  and oi.order_quantity > 1
  and orders.order_date < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '" . $days . " days'
order by orders.order_date
limit 10;
```

If you'd like a more precise answer, you can post your table descriptions on services like these:
https://onecompiler.com/postgresql/3xyf3pfq5

https://rextester.com/LTMNB15242

Then you will get accurate answers like this:
[Count of country of other users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63214388/count-of-country-of-other-users)

Comment: Order Item table does not have customer column

Comment: Can anyone please help me here?

Answer (score 0):

How about a solution like this:

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
    order_no varchar PRIMARY KEY,
    customer_id varchar,
    order_status varchar,
    order_date timestamptz default clock_timestamp()
);

CREATE TABLE orders_items (
    order_id varchar PRIMARY KEY,
    order_no varchar references orders(order_no),
    order_items varchar,
    order_quantity int
);

insert into orders values('on1', 'user_a', 'complete', '2022-12-07 01:56:48.810998+00');
insert into orders values('on2', 'user_b', 'complete', '2022-12-18 01:56:48.810998+00');
insert into orders values('on3', 'user_c', 'complete', '2022-12-09 01:56:48.810998+00');
insert into orders values('on4', 'user_a', 'complete', '2022-12-12 01:56:48.810998+00');
insert into orders values('on5', 'user_b', 'complete', '2022-12-13 01:56:48.810998+00');
insert into orders values('on6', 'user_c', 'complete', '2022-12-14 01:56:48.810998+00');
insert into orders values('on7', 'user_a', 'complete', '2022-12-15 01:56:48.810998+00');
insert into orders values('on8', 'user_b', 'complete', '2022-12-16 01:56:48.810998+00');
insert into orders values('on9', 'user_c', 'complete', '2022-12-17 01:56:48.810998+00');


insert into orders_items values('oi1', 'on1', 'Matrix Serum 250ml', 1);
insert into orders_items values('oi2', 'on1', 'Sunsilk Shampoo 340ml', 1);
insert into orders_items values('oi3', 'on2', 'Sunsilk conditioner 110 ml', 2);
insert into orders_items values('oi4', 'on4', 'Sunsilk Shampoo 340ml', 3);
insert into orders_items values('oi5', 'on1', 'Sunsilk conditioner 110 ml', 1);
insert into orders_items values('oi6', 'on2', 'Sunsilk conditioner 110 ml', 2);
insert into orders_items values('oi7', 'on3', 'Sunsilk conditioner 110 ml', 1);
insert into orders_items values('oi8', 'on2', 'Sunsilk Shampoo 340ml', 2);
insert into orders_items values('oi9', 'on1', 'Sunsilk conditioner 110 ml', 1);

--------------------------------------------------------------

select *
    from orders
    left join orders_items oi on orders.order_no = oi.order_no
where
    oi.order_quantity > 1
    and orders.order_date > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '30 days'
order by orders.order_date
limit 10;
```

Result:

```
 order_no | customer_id | order_status |          order_date           | order_id | order_no |        order_items         | order_quantity 
----------+-------------+--------------+-------------------------------+----------+----------+----------------------------+----------------
 on4      | user_a      | complete     | 2022-12-12 01:56:48.810998+00 | oi4      | on4      | Sunsilk Shampoo 340ml      |              3
 on2      | user_b      | complete     | 2022-12-18 01:56:48.810998+00 | oi3      | on2      | Sunsilk conditioner 110 ml |              2
 on2      | user_b      | complete     | 2022-12-18 01:56:48.810998+00 | oi6      | on2      | Sunsilk conditioner 110 ml |              2
 on2      | user_b      | complete     | 2022-12-18 01:56:48.810998+00 | oi8      | on2      | Sunsilk Shampoo 340ml      |              2
(4 rows)
```

To check the accuracy, add more data to my example.

Here is a working version:
https://onecompiler.com/postgresql/3yue8h74n